# Insert text after some string

Tags: php, regex

I have a page with the following code:

```
'customCode' => 'input name="last_name" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text"  value="{$fields.last_name.value}"'
```

I want to run a script that will add **onblur="name_valid(this.value);"** after *name="last_name"*. The resulting output would look like this:

```
'customCode' => 'input name="last_name" onblur="name_valid(this.value);" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text"  value="{$fields.last_name.value}"
```

Comment: can you explain more..?

Comment: Unclear, very unclear. Do you mean you want to run a script to automatically place that text next to input tags?

Comment: share your code here what you have tried?

Comment: how is the `regex` tag involved in this?

Comment: I have a page editview.php with code `'customCode' => '<input name="last_name"  id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text"  value="{$fields.last_name.value}"> '`     I want to add `onblur="name_valid(this.value);"` when running another script.So the resulting string will be like `'customCode' => '<input name="last_name" onblur="name_valid(this.value);"  id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text"  value="{$fields.last_name.value}" >'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `customCode` is part of an array like so:

`$array1 = array (
      'customCode' => 'input name="last_name" id="last_name"'
);`

You can append a string to `customCode` like that:

`$array1['customCode'] .= ' onblur="function(argument);"';`

You could also use `str_replace()` to work around a closing bracket:

`$array1['customCode'] = str_replace( '>', ' onblur="function(argument);">', $array1['customCode']);`